# syntax error in python while getting data to power bi

Tags: python, rest, powerbi

I am new to python, I am trying to write a script to get data from rest API in Power BI, below is my code:

```
let
token_url = "https://localhost:9002/authorizationserver/oauth/token",    
api_base_url = "https://localhost:9002/rest/v2/apparel-uk/countries",
qry_str = "?fields=DEFAULT",
body="grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=XXX&client_secret=XXX",
Source  = Json.Document(Web.Contents(token_url,
   [ 
    Headers = [#"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],
     Content=Text.ToBinary(body)
   ]
   )
   ),
    token = Source[access_token],

    data= Json.Document(Web.Contents(api_base_url&qry_str,
   [ 
     Headers = [
                #"Authorization"="Bearer "&token,#"Content-Type"="application/json"]
     
   ]
   )
   ),  
in
    data
```

but I am getting an error:

```
Headers = [#"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: still getting syntax error

Comment: Write this in one line  Headers = ["Authorization"="Bearer "&token,"Content-Type"="application/json"]

Comment: done. but i am getting an error on this Headers = [#"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]

Comment: Can you add the link to the community documentation?

Comment: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Power-Query-Open-ID-and-OAuth-2-0-Rest-API/m-p/694264#M334878

Comment: This is not really python is "Power Query M formula language" are you using python support on PowerBI. I'm seeing this video for curiosity :), I didn't know about PowerBI: [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EmALxO7V7y0)

Comment: If you are using python, use the question not the awnser of community link.